# How to have Console mirror output from FileStream?

Tags: c#, console, filestream

I want to be able to have a `FileStream` output to the `Console` for testing purposes.

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void LoggerSetStreamConsole ( ) {
     logManager.WriteLine("LoggerSetStreamConsole: adding logger {0}", Name);
     logger = logManager.Add(this);
     Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(logger.LogStream));

     logger.WriteLine("This is a test of the local logging system writing to the Console.");

     logManager.WriteLine("LoggerSetStreamConsole: removing logger {0}", Name);
     logManager.Remove(this);
  }
```

`logger.LogStream` is a `FileStream`. Is this correct? Since this is running in the MSVS unit testing environment, whenever the code has `Console.Write(...)` there is output in the test results. That is ultimately what I am looking for.

Comment: `SetOut` is supposed to push `Console.WriteLine` to that output isn't it?

Comment: I may take a que from `System.Diagnostics` and figure out how to add a `Listener` that writes to the `Console`.